# How to cite the correct page number from the IEEE Access Journal?

Tags: citations, ieee

I want to cite the IEEE Access journal including the page number.
For instance [the following article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9246536) has page numbers, but they are in the six figure range (i.e `198912` for the first page).
Surely this magazine cannot have that many pages in a single edition, can it?

Is there some encoding scheme of page numbers with this magazine, or can I just use these long numbers?
Apologies if this is super obvious, but I just want to make sure I am doing everything correctly.

Comment: Yes, the page numbers are correct.   It started counting from the first issue and IEEE Access publishes loads of papers, many have questionable quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use these numbers. They are correct.

IEEE Access is 100% digital. There is no print version. The page numbers are there solely for orientation (or perhaps because of outdated metadata-schemes, who knows).

Comment: Thank you very much!